# accessing properties of a mock opened with context manager

Tags: python, testing, mocking

Im trying to mock something but I cant get to the properties of the mock once the it is opened with context

```
# create mocks
mock_1 = MagicMock()
mock_2 = MagicMock()

# set a nested property
type(mock_1.bounds).left = PropertyMock(return_value=-10)
type(mock_2.bounds).left = PropertyMock(return_value= 50)

# at this point I can do less than on the property and it works
mock_1.bounds.left < 50

# setup rasterio mock  open
rasterio_mock = mock_open()
rasterio_mock.side_effect = [mock_1, mock_2]

tiles = []

# add our opened  mocks to list
with patch('rasterio.open', rasterio_mock):
    with ExitStack() as stack:
        tiles.append(stack.enter_context(rasterio.open(f"/vsis3/thing", 'r', driver='GTiff')))
        tiles.append(stack.enter_context(rasterio.open(f"/vsis3/thing", 'r', driver='GTiff')))

        for tile in tiles:
            # same attempt to access the property now  fails :(
            if tile.bounds.left < 50:
                pass
```

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and 'int'
```

Im unsure how to resolve this currently, how can I perform < operations on a property of the mock once it is opened like this? Why isnt the above working?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like this, not sure this is the best way though, Im sure there must be a better way

```
# create mocks
mock_1 = MagicMock()
mock_2 = MagicMock()

# set a nested property
type(mock_1.bounds).left = PropertyMock(return_value=-10)
type(mock_2.bounds).left = PropertyMock(return_value= 50)

# at this point I can do less than on the property and it works
mock_1.bounds.left < 50

mock_01 = MagicMock()
mock_02 = MagicMock()
mock_01.__enter__.return_value = mock_1
mock_02.__enter__.return_value = mock_2


# setup rasterio mock 
rasterio_mock = mock_open()
rasterio_mock.side_effect = [mock_01, mock_02]

tiles = []

# add our opened  mocks to list
with patch('rasterio.open', rasterio_mock):
    with ExitStack() as stack:
        tiles.append(stack.enter_context(rasterio.open(f"/vsis3/thing", 'r', driver='GTiff')))
        tiles.append(stack.enter_context(rasterio.open(f"/vsis3/thing", 'r', driver='GTiff')))

        for tile in tiles:
            # same attempt to access the property fails
            print(tile.bounds.left)
            if tile.bounds.left > 10:
                pass
```